# Web Application for Apache Hive

Tags: java, hadoop, frameworks, appfuse, openxava

I want to develop a Hive Interface, which is uploading contents a excel file to Apache Hive(Big Data) Database using Java. And also, i will get data from other sources using Restful Api and data will store in Hive.

Is it possible to develop this type of application using Appfuse, Openxava, etc framework or can you suggest the frameworks for this type of application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenXava generates the UI automatically from domain classes, so you could create the UI for your application with OpenXava writing transient classes. However, you should write your own code to read and process the data from Hive, OpenXava will not do it for you. Moroever, if you are going to have just a few pages in your UI the avantage of using OpenXava will be small. OpenXava is practical when your application goes against a relational database and have a lot of UI pages.

Comment: Thank u @javierpaniza

Answer (score 0):

Try using Python - Django web application, Pyhive is a package used to interface with Apache Hive.